# ASP.NET Web Api application not running when deployed to IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I have created and Angular / ASP.NET application that work perfectly in VS using IIS Express.  When I deploy it to IIS 8 on Server 2012R2 it does not work.
The Dot Net Framework 4.5 and ASP.NET 4.5 frameworks are installed per the many tutorials that I have found.

The setting: "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" is set true.

My default page 'index.html' is a single page Angular application that does load and execute correctly when I access the application url.  The IIS server is serving up all of the requests without a problem.  Except for routed Web Api requests.  They all return 404.

I also put in some functionality for write to a file in the Application_Start method of Global.asax.  The file is NOT being written.  This tells me that ASP.NET code is not running at all.

I cannot find anything relevant in the Event viewer.  The IIS log simply is telling me about the 404 error.  Same as I am seeing in the network tab of developer tools.

I have searched the net generally, and stackoverflow specifically with no success.

What might I be missing?  How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Thanks

Comment: The best way to troubleshoot this would be to check the developer tools in your browser (F12) and use it to trace the requests to your WebAPI controllers within the 'Network' tab.  This may reveal that the URL is incorrect that is being called when deployed to real IIS or perhaps that the values/verbs being posted are not acceptable to your WebAPI controllers.

Comment: If server returns 404, it seems that IIS is working. Writing a file is another story; many web application doesn't have write access to folder. Could you create one dummy MVC action method with view, and see you can view it inside a browser?

Comment: Are you able to access your API urls directly in browser or from fiddler

Comment: I am having this issue. I have IIS 8 on a Windows XP machine and .NET 4.0. It is hosting MVC4 websites, etc, and all work fine. The simple WebAPI i created works fine locally on VS, but when i upload to the IIS 8 i get 404 error. I know it is related to `Web.config` or some IIS setting.